# How can I get just the site name from the "AppCmd.exe list site" command?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, azure, appcmd

If I run the following command on my server:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list site
```

I get this output:

```
SITE "MyCompany.MyProject.WebRole_IN_0_Web" (id:1273337555,bindings:https/555.555.555.555:443:,state:Started)
```

How can I get just the site name:

```
MyCompany.MyProject.WebRole_IN_0_Web
```

Is some kind of nasty string parsing my only option? The server is a Windows Azure instance.

Comment: why you need that? You need to put that string in a text file or similar things? In this case, consider to use shell script to manipulate strings.

Comment: @Nicola Because it's created dynamically I can't hard-code it, so I need to get it as a variable that I can use in my batch file for some configuration I need to make.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it:

```
appcmd list site /text:name
```

Gives you this:

```
MyCompany.MyProject.WebRole_IN_0_Web
```

The help describes how this works:

```
/text<:value>    Generate output in text format (default).
                 /text:* shows all object properties in detail view.
                 /text:<attribute> shows the value of the specified
                 attribute for each object.
```

I worked out that `name` was the correct attribute by calling:

```
appcmd list site /xml
```

Which returns in XML format (including attribute names):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appcmd>
    <SITE SITE.NAME="MyCompany.MyProject.WebRole_IN_0_Web" SITE.ID="1273337555" bindi
gs="https/555.555.555.555:443:" state="Started" />
</appcmd>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to configure the site/application pool using an AppCmd startup task, check out my recent post about this:

http://mvolo.com/configure-iis-websites-windows-azure-startup-tasks-appcmd/

This covers how to find the site/application pool to edit, and also how to run the task AFTER the site/apppool configuration is created and not before.

Hope this helps.